# drag-drop fails in RF4.2-Final

Tags: richfaces

since I upgraded to RichFaces-4.2/Myfaces-2.1.6 my drag-drop stopped functioning. 
I now get a firebug message saying:

*Sourceform could not be determined, either because element is not attached to a form or we have multiple forms with named elements of the same identifier or name, stopping the ajax processing*

or in Dutch

*De doel form kon niet bepaald worden, ofwel omdat het element niet tot een form behoort, ofwel omdat er verschillende forms zijn met 'named element' met dezelfde identifier of naam, ajax verwerking is gestopt.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
>

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <rich:dragIndicator id="indicator" acceptClass="accept" rejectClass="reject" draggingClass="default">
        <h:graphicImage id="mailDragIcon" url="/images/mail_h20px.png" alt="Sleep bericht" title="Sleep bericht"/>
    </rich:dragIndicator>

    <a4j:log id="log" level="INFO" mode="popup" hotkey="M"/> <!-- Ctrl+Shift+M -->

    <h:form id="formId">
        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 50px;" styleClass="rf-ind-drag">
           <rich:dragSource id="dragSource" dragIndicator="indicator" type="type1" dragValue="#{message.id}"/>
           <h:outputText value="dragSource"/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 50px;">
            <rich:dropTarget id="dragTarget1" acceptedTypes="type1" dropListener="#{messageFolderManager.dropMessage}"/>
            <h:outputText value="dropTarget"/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 50px;">
            <rich:dropTarget id="dragTarget2" acceptedTypes="type2" dropListener="#{messageFolderManager.dropMessage}"/>
            <h:outputText value="dropTarget"/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Milo

Comment: It works under Mojarra 2.1.7 and so I assume an incompatibility between RF4.2 and MyFaces 2.1.6.

Comment: Not fixed in richfaces 4.2.1-20120229.011144-4

Answer (score 1):

Without `rich:dragIndicator` it also works under **Myfaces 2.0.2**.